# Error when I click the second time on a Menu Item in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I am writing an NSApplication (Swift 5.0, Storyboard, MacOS) with several windows.
I am struggling with the Manu.

I want that a MenuItem close all the open windows and open a new window with the MainFrame of the app.

To do so, I connected the MenuItem to the following action in the AppDelegate :

```
@IBAction func menuMain(_ sender: Any) {
    let windowController1 = NSApplication.shared.orderedWindows
    for windows in windowController1 {
        windows.close()
    }
    let mainStoryBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "MainFrame3") as! NSViewController
    
    let window = NSWindow()
    window.contentViewController = viewController
    window.makeKey()
    window.setIsVisible(true)
}
```

The first time that I click on the menu Item everything works fine. But the second time I click on it, the app crashes and I get the following error pointing to the AppDelegate file:
"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Comment: Hi you should be capable of view the complete stack trace. Probably there are more information on the console. I'd suggest you create a lazy var for instatiate the controller like lazy var     let viewController = { mainStoryBoard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "MainFrame3") as! NSViewController
} that way you only have one instance of this controller not as many as user clicks.

Comment: The window is released twice when `close()` is called, call `window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false`.

Comment: @JBarros35, the console is clean without error messages. Thanks for your help but even if i instantiate the controller as you said the error still persist.

Comment: @Willeke, Thanks for your help. Calling window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false prevents the app from crashing. But after that, if I press one of the buttons inside MainFrame3 I got the error again ("Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0") and the app crashes. No error is printed in the console.